# Prove that $\prec$ is irreflexive and transitive

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Note: Definitions I use (Velleman's *How To Prove It*)

> If $A$ and $B$ are
>    sets, then we will say that $B$ *dominates* $A$, and write $A \precsim B$,
>    if there is a function $f: A \rightarrow B$ that is one-to-one. If $A
> \precsim B$ and $A \nsim B$, then we say that $B$ *strictly dominates*
>    $A$, and write $A \prec B$.
>
> $A \sim B$ means $A$ is *equinumerous* with B, which means there is a
>    function $f: A \rightarrow B$ that is bijective.

This is my question: I'm trying to prove that $\prec$  is transitive.

Here's my idea so far,

I know that for $\prec$ to be transitive,

For all sets $A, B, C$, if $A \prec B$ and $B \prec C$ then $A \prec C$.

This means for my proof I suppose $A, B, C$ to be arbitrary sets. Then I suppose $A \prec B$ and $B \prec C$. My goal would be to show $A \prec C$ which means I have to show that $A \precsim C$ and $A \nsim C$. From my goals I know that  $A \precsim B$ and $A \nsim B$ and  $B \precsim C$ and $B \nsim C$. From a previous proof I know that if $A \precsim B$ and $B \precsim C$ then $A \precsim C$, so we are done with the first goal. My problem is I don't know how to use my remaining assumptions to prove $A \nsim C$.

Could someone tell me how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just for future reference, it's customary, when writing things like $A \precsim C$, to include both $A$ and $C$ in mathmode: So instead of writing `A $\precsim$ C`, most would write `$A \precsim C$`.

Answer (score 1):

You know that there exist injective functions $f, g$

$$A \overset{f}{\hookrightarrow} B \overset{g}{\hookrightarrow} C$$

since $A \prec B \prec C.$

I assume you have the Cantor-Bernstein theorem, that $P \sim Q$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ inject into each other. This means that, since $B$ strictly dominates $A$, and $C$ strictly dominates $B$, any functions $f', g'$

$$A \overset{f'}{\leftarrow} B, \qquad B \overset{g'}{\leftarrow} C$$ cannot be injective. **Note:** We really just need any result that says $C$ can't inject into $B$, and $B$ can't inject into $A$. Do you have any result like that, if not Cantor-Bernstein? I don't know if you've already shown it's irreflexive.

However, if $A \sim C$, then there would necessarily be a function $h'$

$$A \overset{h'}{\hookleftarrow}C$$

that's injective. Thus, my hint is:

Using the functions above, consider what must be true of $f \circ h'$.

Comment: I did show it was irreflexive.

Comment: OK, so you the above should be enough.